# Confusing Java data structure - static HashMap of own class

Tags: java

I am a Java beginner. Recently I try to study the Java code of my company system and I come up with a very confusing data structure. It is a static variable of HashMap, but the HashMap is type of it class...

This is the example.

```
public class CustomerList{
    static ByteHashMap<CustomerList> Element1 = new HashMap<CustomerList>();
    static ByteHashMap<CustomerList> Element2 = new HashMap<CustomerList>();
    static ByteHashMap<List<CustomerList>> Element1 = new HashMap<List<CustomerList>>();
....
}
```

Can anyone explain to me the purpose of this kind of data structure? And in what perspective should I understand this data structure?
edit: The ByteHashMap is come from a open source library

Comment: Are you sure about the code you posted? There's nothing strange in the data structure per se, as they're regular `HashMap`s. Since they're `static` members, all the `CustomerList` instances will share their content, which sounds a bit strange, unless there's a `static { ... } ` block somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt what you published is valid code because `Map` or `HashMap` takes 2 parameter types i.e. `Map<K, V>`.

If you are actually asking about the practice to set a static structure of its own type on the class level, then yes its OK. It's a convenient way to keep a global collection of a certain class. One sample usage is when you want to ensure == equality when object equals and to return the unique instance.

Comment: Thank for reply. Actually the original code is using ByteHashMap(seem to be a part of open source library), it only take one argument.

Comment: But if the map is read and written from several threads without the proper synchronization, concurrency problems may arise.

Comment: Concurrency isn't a reason not to use class level static variable. Usually using class level static variable is a class design facet; while concurrency is more an infrastructure level concern which is easy to address given all the threading and concurrency classes in Java.

Answer (score 0):

In first example of HashMap, we will create and add object into our Map. Always use Generics, if you are not working in Java 1.4. Following code will create HashMap with keys of  type String and values of type Integer with default size and load factor.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> cache = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

alternatively you can create HashMap from copying data from another Map or Hashtable as shown in below example:

```
Hashtable<Integer, String> source = new Hashtable<Integer,String>();
HashMap<Integer, String>  map = new HashMap(source);
```

You can also supply load factor (percentage of size, which if fulled trigger resize of HashMap) and initialiCapacity while creating instance by using overloaded constructor provided in API. Adding elements, also called put operation, requires key and value object. Here is an example of adding key and value in Java HashMap:

```
map.put(21, "Twenty One");
map.put(21.0, "Twenty One"); //this will throw compiler error because 21.0 is not integer
```

for more details please refer

```
http://java67.blogspot.in/2013/02/10-examples-of-hashmap-in-java-programming-tutorial.html
```